# A bytes-like object is required, not 'str' f.write(image_url)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
while b<120:
        
        b+=1
        saveimage= str(b+1) + ".jpg"
        images = soup.find_all(id="image-"+str(b)+"")
        for image in images:
            
            resim=image['src']
            image_url=resim[7:]
            
            
            print('Bölüm '+str(i)+ ' ' +str(saveimage))

            with open(yol+saveimage, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(image_url)
```

`A bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`   I get an error. I can't use request because they use Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1):

> with open(yol+saveimage, 'wb')

You used 'wb' (write bytes), so it fails when you are writing a string
You can instead use with

> open(yol+saveimage, 'w')